# What's the difference between using AbstractBehavior and AbstractActor to define Akka Actors?

Tags: akka, actor

I've started learning Akka actors recently and seen actors defined in two ways.

```
class Main extends AbstractBehavior<String>
```

and

```
class SomeActor extends AbstractActor
```

I'm following the Java API and could someone explain the difference or point to article that does ?

Comment: you can read https://www.baeldung.com/akka-actors-java to get some brief idea about akka actors. After reading the you can continue with the official documentation i.e. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/introduction.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> class Main extends AbstractBehavior

Is Akka Typed, which is the way to define Actor Behavior from Akka 2.6. It is in 2.5 but as experimental.

> class SomeActor extends AbstractActor

Is for untyped Actors, named classic Actors as of Akka 2.6.

If you're on Akka 2.6 I'd suggest using AbstractBehavior and following the try-akka guide: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-java/