# what is the difference between AbstractActor, UntypedActor and AbstractBehavior in akka?

Tags: java, akka

New to Akka here, I have three different examples and all three use very different classes for implementing an actor,

AbstractActor: https://www.baeldung.com/akka-with-spring

UntypedActor: https://www.baeldung.com/akka-actors-java

AbstractBehavior: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_1.html

The first two look very simple and straightforward and resemble the actor model implementation I have used and seen on Erlang.
The one from the official docs looks like the most complex one.

So I am a bit confused on which one to use and when?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using AbstractBehavior and AbstractActor to define Akka Actors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263528/whats-the-difference-between-using-abstractbehavior-and-abstractactor-to-define)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `akka.actor.typed.javadsl.AbstractBehavior` is the new "typed" Java API for actors, it is slightly more verbose but gives you better type safety back in return for that vebosity. We recommend new projects starting out with Akka to use this from 2.6 and moving forward.
- `akka.actor.AbstractActor` is the "classic" (pre Akka 2.6) Java API for actors, it was added with support for Lambdas in Java 8. It is not going away because of the new APIs but will be around for a long while since many systems are built using it.
- `akka.actor.UntypedActor` was an older Java API for actors before Java 8, it was deprecated in Akka 2.5 and has now (2.6) been removed.